# Updating template data extjs

Tags: extjs

I am making a window with a panel that holds a `tpl` config and I have passed a config which I named `recordref` to the window component like the following, I wish to update the `tpl` config with the data in the recordref.

```
rowdblclick: function(view, record,element,rowIndex,e,eOpts){
    var me = this;
    Ext.create('MyWindow',{
            recordref: record
    });
}
```

My window looks like this

```
Ext.define('MyWindow',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.details',
    controller: 'details',
    ghost: false,
    constrain: true,
    title: 'Details',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            reference: 'infopanel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    tpl: ['<p>Name: {name}</p>',
                          '<p>Age: {age}</p>'],
                    listeners: {
                        render: 'updateTpl'
                    }
                },
                ... other items ...
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

and the function `updateTpl` in the window's controller looks like

```
updateTpl: function(panel, eOpts){
    var me = this;
    var view = me.getView();
    var record = view.recordref;
    panel.update(record);
}
```

This code however leads to this error

```
app.js?_dc=1502746390069:102863 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at constructor.overwrite (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:102863)
at constructor.overwrite (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:51335)
at constructor.update (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:65016)
at constructor.updateTpl (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:180214)
at constructor.fire (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:18721)
at constructor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:19625)
at constructor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:62695)
at constructor.prototype.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:52784)
at constructor.fireEventArgs (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:19478)
at constructor.fireEvent (app.js?_dc=1502746390069:19437)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `render` isn't an appropriate time to do that. Why are you doing it in a render listeners at all?

Comment: Thanks, I used the `afterrender` event instead and it worked when I used `record.getData()` like @xhadon suggested. Just wondering though, why can't it be done in the on render event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the data object to the panels update function.

```
panel.update(record.getData());
```

The [update](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-update) function expects *htmlOrData* as first parameter. You could do this as well:

```
panel.update({
        name: record.get('name'),
        age: record.get('age')
    })
```

Comment: Got it to work using a `afterrender` event and `record.getData()`